# Web Api OdataController PATCH action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am working on building CRUD OData (`ODataController`) controllers. For this request

> PATCH http://localhost/MySite/api/MyData(1)

a *PATCH* action declared as below works. The model has single property marked with `KeyAttribute`

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch(
    [FromODataUri] int key, 
    Delta<MyModel> modelDelta)
```

This one doesn't work (note that I named parameter `id` instead of `key`). It returns 404 - resource not found:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch(
   [FromODataUri] int id, // <--- invalid argument name?
   Delta<MyModel> modelDelta)
```

I also tried to mark this action with `[ODataRoute("({id})")]` but I get this

> The path template '({id})' on the action 'Patch' in controller 'MyData' is not a valid OData path template. Empty segment encountered in request URL. Please make sure that a valid request URL is specified.

Do I have flexibility to name parameters specifically? And especially when I may have 2-3 keys/parameters. I want to be able to use `patch` as

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch(
     [FromODataUri] int id1, 
     [FromODataUri] int id2, 
     Delta<MyModel> modelDelta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your class declared like this:

```
//Must declare this attribute to relative ODataRoute Works
[ODataRoutePrefix("MyData")]
public class MyDataController : ODataController
```

....

otherwise must declare the route

```
[ODataRoute("MyData({id})")]
...
```